# get status for library based on start and end time from table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 tables one library details and other is library timings

```
CREATE TABLE `library_details` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `library_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

INSERT INTO library_details VALUES(1,"library1");

```
CREATE TABLE `library_timing` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `library_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_library_timing_1` (`library_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_library_timing_1` FOREIGN KEY (`library_id`) REFERENCES `library_details` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

INSERT INTO library_timing VALUES(1,1,08:30,18:00);

i need to get the data as follows

```
   ----------------------------------
   id | name     | status | nextopentime |
   -----------------------------------
    1 | library1 | 0/1    | (could be in hrs)
```

status based on open close time 1 for open 0 for close

i can get the id and name using join but i am not sure how to calculate the other 2 fields

Comment: Provide: CREATE TABLE for tables, INSERT INTO with sample data, desired result for this data.

Comment: done i have added the requried@Akina

Comment: it is just a sample insert there will be many librarys data i have added the desired output @Akina

Comment: NOT approximate or like a pattern! Precise output, for provided data strongly! PS. Anything that is not explicitly described will be done somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly then maybe something like this would be what you are looking for:

```
select ld.id
       , ld.library_name
       , case when curtime() between lt.start_time and lt.end_time then
                 '1'
              else
                 '0'
              end "status"
       , case when (curtime() - lt.end_time) >  (curtime() - lt.start_time) 
              and curtime() not between lt.start_time and lt.end_time then 
                 subtime(curtime() , lt.end_time)
              when (curtime() - lt.end_time) <  (curtime() - lt.start_time) 
              and curtime() not between lt.start_time and lt.end_time then
                 subtime( lt.start_time, curtime())
              else
                 '00:00:00'
              end "next open time"
from library_details ld
join library_timing lt on lt.id = ld.id;
```

[here is a small demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f62a9bd05ecfaeda3860ec0dde5e17ac)

As you can see in my example if the library is open(status = 1) then the value in the column "next open time" will be 00:00:00.

If you want to add 24 hours you can do that like this:

```
addtime(subtime( lt.start_time, curtime()), "24:00:00")
```

Comment: subtime(curtime() , lt.end_time) can we add 24 hrs?? it is giving in -ve

Comment: Hi @munch2 please can you explain this : " it is giving in -ve", I do not understand what does it mean...